# Unable to dequeue single cell in collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have come across a very disturbing issue in which I am not able to dequeue only a single cell in `collectionView`. When there are more than one item in `collectionView`, it works fine but soon as I have an array with a single item, it doesn't show any cell. I am not able to figure it out what’s wrong with my code.

```
extension collectionview: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell
        return cell
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The number returned for numberOfItemsInSection should be the total number of objects you want to show, so if you have an array of objects for example, you would want to return the count of that array. Since it's currently set to one, only one item will be shown. If you change that to match the number of items you're displaying, then the collectionView should cooperate.

Answer (score 0):

First:
the returned of `numberOfItemsInSection`will be `array.count` for Example

```
var array = [model]()
```

Then in `cellForItemAt` you should configure your cell with data so
Add this block in your cell class

```
func configureCell(_ data: model) { 
   // code for cell view 
}
```

Finally `cellForItemAt` will be

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell
    cell.configureCell(array[indexPath.item])
    return cell
}
```

I hope this be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Needless to say, collection views work fine with only one cell. Your code is insufficient to manifest the problem you describe.

But here are a few observations/suggestions:

1. Add breakpoint or debugging log statement in `numberOfItemsInSection` and make sure it’s getting called. If not, then you likely have one of a variety of different possible problems:

   - Make sure you set the “data source” for the collection view (either in IB or programmatically). Merely conforming to `UICollectionViewDataSource` is not sufficient: You actually have to set the data source of the collection view.
   - Make sure you set the base class for your storyboard scene to be the view controller in question.
   - Make sure you put these `UICollectionViewDataSource` methods in the right object.
2. I notice that you've put these methods as an extension to `collectionview`.

   - Class names should, as a matter of convention, always start with upper case letter.
   - Usually the `UICollectionViewDataSource` methods are put in the view controller (or, less common, a dedicated object that you'll vend and to which keep your own strong reference). I'm not sure what to make of your class named `collectionview`.

But, in short, there is no problem having collection views with only one cell. Your problem rests elsewhere.